# TypeError: $container.isotope is not a function (Wordpress & Isotope)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have a problem with isotope & wordpress. Im using an easy script which is not working when integrated into wordpress. I get the following error:

> TypeError: $container.isotope is not a function". This is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    /* ISOTOPE */
    var $container = $('.flex-grid');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        isAnimated: false,
        transitionDuration: 0,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        }
    });
});
```

The script is loaded in the side footer as the last script.

Comment: Try moving the script from footer to header, and make sure it depends on `jQuery` while enqueueing it.

Comment: I moved the script to the header, right after jQuery and jQuery migrate script. Still the same error.

Comment: But did you put the [dependency](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)?

Comment: Hey dingo i got it. Isotope was somehow integrated twice now its working... sorry my fault... Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

you need to import isotope.js scripts  after importing jQuery

get it from here

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#cdn